# How to escape angle brackets in mappings (the ones that appear in <esc> and <cr>)?

Tags: key-bindings, escape

I am making a complex mapping that requires me to insert angle brackets (`<`and `>`) but I do not know how to escape them so Vim does not interpret them as special key-codes.

It seems like escaping them are not required if you do a simple mapping like:

```
nnoremap <leader>x yi<pppp
```

But my mapping looks more like this:

```
nnoremap <leader>x a<?<<cr>lyi</<<cr>a/<c-r>"><esc>
```

And I become really confused about all angle brackets. I also think that Vim might become confused.

Is there a way to escape angle brackets when making mappings in Vim?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do so with `<lt>` (see `:h <lt>`) :

```
nnoremap <leader>x a<lt>CR>
```

Will enter `<CR>` literaly, whereas :

```
nnoremap <leader>x a<CR>
```

Will execute `<CR>`

Comment: Thank you! Seven years later, I was trying to create a mapping to list my custom leader mappings and Vim was expanding `<Leader>` in the right-hand side of my mapping so it didn't work. Finally put together the right search terms to find this post, and `<lt>` is the literal I was looking for, I hadn't thought to check for an angle-bracket literal for angle brackets!